# Session get erased on refresh in Codeigniter 4.3.3

Tags: session, codeigniter-4

I am using CI 4.3 for my project, I have noticed session gets erased after redirect or refresh, also my session writeable creates multiple session files for each request.

my project structure is like

```
- application-1
------ app
------ config
------ controller
------ public
------ writeable
------ etc
------ etc

- application-2
------ app
------ config
------ controller
------ public
------ writeable
------ etc
------ etc

- system
```

Sample Controller Redirect

```
$login = $this->login->data();
$session = \Config\Services::session();
$session->set('login',$login);
return redirect()->to('application-1/access/dashboard');
```

I can get session variables on 'application-1/access/dassboard' only once with

```
print_r(session('login'));
```

Session is then destroyed automatically on page refresh or redirect.

I want the session to be stable on refresh or redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my simple answer can help You.

for me, just adding the `session();` at the of the InitController inside BaseController.php.

so You can save Your Session until expired.